# LEFT JOIN Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Volunteer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L)    
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50L)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)


class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, unique=True)
    overseer = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100L, null=True)


class DepartmentVolunteer(models.Model):
    volunteer = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    assistant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    keyman = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    captain = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100L, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to query for all departments that have no volunteers assigned to them. I can do so using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    d.name 
FROM   
    vsp_department AS d
LEFT JOIN vsp_departmentvolunteer AS dv
ON d.id = dv.department_id  
WHERE
    dv.department_id IS NULL;
```

Is there a more django-like way of doing this or should i just go with raw sql?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this by following the backwards relation in the lookup.

```
>>> qs = Department.objects.filter(
...     departmentvolunteer__isnull=True).values_list('name', flat=True)
>>> print(qs.query)
SELECT "app_department"."name" 
FROM "app_department" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_departmentvolunteer" 
ON ( "app_department"."id" = "app_departmentvolunteer"."department_id" )
WHERE "app_departmentvolunteer"."id" IS NULL
```

Here are the docs on queries "Spanning multi-valued relationships": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: Thanks! I'll compare your solution with mine.

Comment: Is your query checking against the id field in DepartmentVolunteer? Or will Django make the relationship and check against the department_id field?

Comment: It's checking against the `department` column in the `DepartmentVolunteer` which is a FK to `Departement` and hence matches on its ID.

Comment: This is an outer join. What if you don't want the right join matches in there too...?

Comment: In mine, the query is an `INNER JOIN`. I am using `django 1.11.20`. Any thoughts on how to do a left join? I need an `INNER JOIN` with some `LEFT JOIN`. I've been trying to search it but not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 26):

To me were need custom join models, that have implicit fields (no have ForeignKey relation)

it work to me on django 1.9.
but it more seem on the crutch
If someone have more elegant solution please share for people

```
from django.db.models.sql.datastructures import Join
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignObject
from django.db.models.options import Options
from myapp.models import Ace
from myapp.models import Subject

jf = ForeignObject(
    to=Subject,
    on_delete=lambda: x, 
    from_fields=[None], 
    to_fields=[None], 
    rel=None, 
    related_name=None   
)

jf.opts = Options(Ace._meta)
jf.opts.model = Ace
jf.get_joining_columns = lambda: (("subj", "name"),)

j=Join(
    Subject._meta.db_table, Ace._meta.db_table, 
    'T1', "LEFT JOIN", jf, True)

q=Ace.objects.filter(version=296)
q.query.join(j)

print q.query
```

result:

```
SELECT
    `ace`.`id`,
    `ace`.`version_id`,
    `ace`.`obj`,
    `ace`.`subj`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Type`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Inheritance`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Rights`
FROM `ace`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `core_subject`
ON (`ace`.`subj` = `core_subject`.`name`)
WHERE `ace`.`version_id` = 296
```

here example of use with additional condition and set table alias(but it seem as crutch)

```
def join_to(self, table1, table2, field1, field2, queryset, alias=''):
    """
    table1 base
    """
    # here you can set complex clause for join
    def extra_join_cond(where_class, alias, related_alias):
        if (alias, related_alias) == ('[sys].[columns]',
                                      '[sys].[database_permissions]'):
            where = '[sys].[columns].[column_id] = ' \
                    '[sys].[database_permissions].[minor_id]'
            children = [ExtraWhere([where], ())]
            wh = where_class(children)
            return wh
        return None

    dpj = ForeignObject(
        to=table2,
        on_delete=lambda: None,
        from_fields=[None],
        to_fields=[None],
        rel=None,
        related_name=None
    )
    dpj.opts = Options(table1._meta)
    dpj.opts.model = table1
    dpj.get_joining_columns = lambda: ((field1, field2),)
    dpj.get_extra_restriction = extra_join_cond

    dj = Join(
        table2._meta.db_table, table1._meta.db_table,
        'T', "LEFT JOIN", dpj, True)

    ac = queryset._clone()
    ac.query.join(dj)
    # hook for set alias
    alias and setattr(dj, 'table_alias', alias)
    return ac
```

i use it by

```
# how it use:
from django.db.models.expressions import Col  

q = Something.objects \
    .filter(type__in=["'S'", "'U'", "'G'"]) \
    .exclude(name__in=("'sys'", "'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'")) \
    .annotate(
        ... some annotation fields
        class_= Col(Permissions._meta.db_table,
                    Permissions._meta.get_field('field_name'),
                    output_field=IntegerField()),
        Grant=Col(
            'T10',
            Principals._meta.get_field('name'),
            output_field=CharField()),
     ).values('Grant')  
     
     ac = self.join_to(Principals, ServerPrincipals, 'sid', 'sid', q)
     # here invoke "extra_join_cond" of function "join_to"
     ac = self.join_to(Permissions, Columns, 'major_id', 'object_id', ac)
     # here use alias table
     ac = self.join_to(Permissions, Principals, 'grantor_id', 'principal_id', ac, 'T10')  # T10 is alias
```

sql'll be

```sql
SELECT
    T10.name    AS Grant
FROM sys.principals
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals 
        ON (sys.principals.sid = sys.server_principals.sid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns 
        ON (sys.permissions.major_id = sys.columns.object_id 
        AND (
           (sys.columns.column_id = sys.permissions.minor_id))
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.principals T10 
    ON (sys.permissions.grantor_id = T10.principal_id)
```

Comment: excellent! You made my day sir. For adding a little complement, I already had the Join created with my query, so my solution was to override it ;)`queryset.query.alias_map['my_outer_table'].join_field.get_extra_restriction = extra_join_cond`

Comment: Thanks @madjardi. Your answer helped me in solving this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42816689/2367394

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be working:

```
Department.objects.filter(departmentvolunteer__department__isnull=True)
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

for create custom join by **OR**

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(AceViewSet, self).get_queryset()
    qs = qs.select_related('xxx')
    # construct all tables and the join dependence
    qs.query.__str__()

    qs.query.alias_map['xx_subject'].join_cols = (('xxx_id', 'uid'), ('xxx_id', 'ad_subject_id'))
    qs.query.alias_map['xx_subject'].as_sql = partial(self.as_sql, qs.query.alias_map['xx_subject'])
    return qs

@staticmethod
def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
    sql, params = Join.as_sql(self, compiler, connection)
    or_sql = sql.replace("AND", "OR")
    return or_sql, params
```

```sql
FROM "xx_ace"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "xx_subject"
    ON ("xx_ace"."xxx_id" = "xx_subject"."uid" OR "xx_ace"."xxx_id" = "xx_subject"."ad_subject_id")
```