# Django ORM join with self after aggregation

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, join, django-orm

I am trying to write an ORM query to join a table with itself after aggregation (Hence `select_related` etc won't work). The corresponding SQL query is as below

```
select * from 
transaction t 
join
(
   select account_id, sum(amount) as total_amount 
   from transaction 
   where amount > 0 
   group by account_id
) aggr
on t.account_id = aggr.account_id
where amount > 0.4 * total_amount;
```

So far no luck. I even tried the `join_to/CustomJoin` from [Django ORM. Joining subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902263/django-orm-joining-subquery/42816689#42816689), but this didn' work.

Edit. Models are as below

```
class Account(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Transaction(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, db_constraint=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    booking_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant *models*? Usually it is better not to think in terms of queries in Django, but in terms of models.