# Django multiple left joins

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how to implement in Django the following left join sql query.
I already know about Person.objects.raw()

```
select person.name, phone.number, email.emailaddr, home.address
from person
left join phone
    on person.id = phone.person_id
left join email
    on person.id = email.person_id
left join home
    on person.id = home.person_id;
```

assuming the following model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Phone(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')

class Email(models.Model):
    emailaddr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')

class Home(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person')
```

Comment: I answered below because it was quick and easy, but I should point out that this question [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271835/left-join-django-orm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
Person.objects.values_list(
    'name', 
    'phone__number', 
    'email__emailaddr', 
    'home__address'
)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I'm surprised it does.  I had thought you must use the "_set.all()" to get the other side of a foreign key relationship.

Comment: Nah, the `__` is pretty powerful.  Since it worked, do you mind accepting the answer (hit the check mark)?  Thanks!