# Django ORM for SQL query with multiple left joins

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-queryset

I have a SQL query which I am trying to make it as a Django ORM, tried many ways but didn't get the exact solution for it.

```
select c.* from product p 
left join voucher v on v.id = p.voucher_id
left join customer c on c.id = v.customer_id
where p.id=3;
```

Django Model are,

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", db_index=True)
   mobile = models.IntegerField(default='')

class Voucher(models.Model):
    voucher_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,db_index=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    rate = models.FloatField(max_length=50)
    voucher = models.ForeignKey(Voucher, db_index=True)
```

Comment: I understood your problem, can you please describe your Django model.

Comment: Added my django model @AnkitKumarRathod

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT JOIN Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271835/left-join-django-orm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `select_related`

ORM: `Product.objects.filter(id=3).select_related('voucher__customer')`

`select_related` works by creating a SQL join [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Hi @Farhadur, this works fine can I also get the reverse of it meaning with the help of customer can I get all products for that customer?

Comment: Yes you can, you have to use `prefetch_related`  [related article](https://medium.com/@lucasmagnum/djangotip-select-prefetch-related-e76b683aa457)