# Left Join in Django ORM

Tags: django, orm, left-join

Say I have models called "Post" and "Reaction" and I have made a Post, saved it and now I want to react on it with a Reaction.
Now, when I visit my feed where a list of Posts is, I want to show my reaction if I had one.

Which means:
`{% if post.my_reaction %}{{ post.my_reaction.contents }}{% endif %}`
Now, obviously I want to load more than just one Post; posts which don't have my reactions on it.

I know that I used to solve this with SQL in PHP with

```
SELECT * FROM Post 
LEFT JOIN Reaction ON Reaction.Post = Post.id AND Reaction.Author = <me>
```

My models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)

class Reaction(models.Model):
    reaction = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reactions")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It's not quite clear how I could achieve this in Django

Comment: can you show your models.py?

Comment: maybe this is what you're looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688104/4996863

Comment: @Charnel no that is not what I am looking for. I'm explicitly searching for a left join that if a post has my reaction on it, that entry in the query has the reaction object in it.

Comment: ok, let's ask another question - since `content` is a field on `Post` model, the only thing you need `Reaction` here is to just know if user reacted on post or not? If yes, this seems to be a simple boolean flag that could be added with annotation.

Comment: Can a user have more than 1 reaction per post?

Comment: @IainShelvington no, just one. Much like the "Like" function on Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop into `raw`:

```
results = Post.objects.raw("""
SELECT * FROM Post 
LEFT outer JOIN Reaction ON Reaction.Post = Post.id AND Reaction.Author = %s
""", [ '<me>', ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by creating a custom template tag to query the posts for the logged in user. Although it's optional, to me a good place for that query to live would be on the Post model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)

   def user_reactions(self, user):
        return self.reactions.filter(author=user)
```

You would then need to create  a custom template tag to call that method on the post object while passing in the user from the request.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag # (Django >= 1.9, earlier versions need to use `assignment_tag`)
def post_user_reactions(post, user):
    return post.user_reactions(user)
```

This would return a queryset of reactions for that user, which you can then iterate through in the template:

```
{% post_user_reactions post user as user_reactions %}
{% for reaction in user_reactions %}
  Do stuff with reaction object
{% endfor %}
```

Please keep in mind that making database queries in a for-loop (as you probably are, say if you're displaying a list of posts in this case), can end up being very expensive. You'll want to add a `prefetch_related` or a queryset annotation to do this.

As some advice, the Django ORM is a slightly different way of thinking about database access than traditional SQL. Thinking about 'left joins' won't help - you need to think in terms of Django objects and their relationships.