# How to join like sql in django models

Tags: django

I have these three models which has not contained foreign key

```
class SchoolReg(models.Model):
    # TODO: Define fields here
    user = models.ForeignKey('front.User', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length= 50)

class CandidateCode(models.Model):
    candidateCode = models.IntegerField()
    regId = models.IntegerField()
    regCategory = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Sec1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null = True)
    centreName = models.CharField(max_length= 50, blank= True, null = True)
    compRegNo = models.CharField(max_length= 50, blank= True, null = Tru
```

now I want join these models and make a queryset of student like this

```
SELECT * from school_reg s
LEFT JOIN sec1 c on s.user_id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN candidate_code cc on cc.reg_id = s.school_id
WHERE c.center_name = "centreName"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: I made the sql query now I want to make the same query in Django ORM Model

Comment: want to join these three models SchoolReg.user == Sec1.user and then SchoolReg.id == CandidateCode.regId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use `select_related()` because we don't have foreign key here so on that time we use raw sql
[performing raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

I use this for the solution

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT s.id, s.dob, cc.candidateCode, s.fullname,  
    q.title, e.examDate, c.centreName from lrnadmin_schoolreg s
    LEFT JOIN lrnadmin_bookingexam e on s.exam_id = e.id
    LEFT JOIN front_sec1 c ON s.user_id = c.user_id
    LEFT JOIN lrnadmin_qualification q ON q.id = s.qualification_id
    LEFT JOIN lrnadmin_candidatecode cc ON cc.regId = s.id
    WHERE c.id = %s""", [request.POST['centre']])
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify the relationship on the filter statement [according to the documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

[This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21272153) even has a great suggestion of using the `.query()` method to reverse a specific lookup you need.

Comment: I can join two model but how can I join with 3rd models

Comment: @HabibUrRehman Show the code how you tried to join the 2 models

Comment: @viam0Zah 
sec1 = Sec1.objects.get(centreName = "centreName") 
students = SchoolReg.objects.filter(user = sec1.user).all()

Comment: the problem is that Now I have multiple objects in students and  I want join with third model CandidateCode

Comment: I want something like this get both values of these models
ca = CandidateCode.objects.filter(regId = students.id).all()

Comment: Please make the above sql query in orm model

Comment: from this query I can get only CandidateCode models values but I want both CandidateCode and SchoolReg values
s = CandidateCode.objects.filter(regId__in = [s.id for s in students]).all()