# How to convert this raw query into Django ORM

Tags: django, django-queryset

`SELECT * FROM SUbPlans LEFT JOIN orders on SUbPlans.empId=orders.selected_id where orders.user_id=2`

I have this query that I want to convert into Django ORM.

I just want to do this using select_related. SUbPlans and orders are connected via foriegn key

my attempt:

```
user_sub_plans = SUbPlans.objects.select_related(id=request.user).first()
```

Comment: You will have to show us the models.

Comment: That may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271835/left-join-django-orm

Comment: Models name is `SUbPlans` and `orders`.

Comment: What have you tried, what errors have you encountered?

Comment: Only This : `user_sub_plans = SUbPlans.objects.select_related(id=request.user).first() `

Comment: Please show model definition, give us sample datasets and desired output for those datasets. Currently your question is unclear. Even the original query lacks sense: predicate in `WHERE` turns your `LEFT` into `INNER`. So what was the intent is terribly unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

try to fetch your SUbPlans first and then all related orders using prefetch_related like

```
from django.db.models import Q    
SUbPlans.objects.prefetch_related('orders').filter(Q(orders__isnull=True) | Q(orders__selected_id=2)).all()
```